# Publicar no Twitter com PHP

Tags: php, twitter-api

Fiz esse código para publicar as notícias do meu site direto no meu Twitter, mas não está funcionando e não consigo identificar o erro, já que não retorna nada. Não funciona e não da erro, simplesmente nada acontece. Procurei em vários lugares, mas não consegui achar uma solução.

```
$resultado = 'Publicar no Twitter';

require_once 'twitteroauth.php';

define("CONSUMER_KEY","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
define("OAUTH_SECRET","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $resultado));
```

Comment: Veja se dá algum aviso ou erro no Inspect Element do Google Chrome.

Comment: O código esta funcionando perfeitamente, o problema estava em um `select` que estava à cima. Não pensei que fosse a consulta no banco de dados, pois não retornava erro, mas já arrumei e agora esta tudo certo.